# Can I depend on IE's Browser mode and doctype to debug issues for IE 8 and below + Quirks?

Tags: debugging, testing, cross-browser, compatibility

If I use the F12 Developer Tools to debug for IE, can I depend on the "Browser Mode" and "Doctype" to debug issues for IE8 and below?

By debugging I mostly mean for overall page behavior... HTML/CSS, A client says "The dropdown doesn't work in IE8", I have IE9... Instinct is to hit F12 and change the doctype or browser mode and test.

Comment: It can give you a quick yay/nay kind of test, but the straight plain fact is that it is "emulating" IE8 and thus is not exactly the same.  In some cases it will highlight the issue for you, but it isn't perfect.  I have found issues with "real" IE8 that can't be reproduced in the Dev Tools of IE9/IE10.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.

I would **not recommend** using compatibility mode.  I have never quite understood why `MS` doesn't seem to do what `Mozilla` and `Google` do which is, *disallow the use of deprecated tags*.  As an example, at my work, we have two tiers of browser usage, tier 1 and tier 2.  Tier one consists of:  `Safari` (oddly enough, we get quite a few customers buying via their iPads), `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `IE9`.  Tier two is:  `IE8` and the rest of the pile.  Recently, we had a bug where some `checkboxes` where not rendering correctly in `**only IE8**`; but worked fine in `IE7` and `IE9`.  The moral here is that using compatibility mode is testing under an assumption, and if you want thorough and correct testing, you cannot assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Quirks mode, but that's not 100% the same. If you are lucky, you will hit the same bug also in quirks mode.

The only sure way is to use a IE8. There are cross-browser testing tools that enable you to do so without any installs.

Just for bug reporduction purposes http://www.modern.ie/virtualization-tools offers some VM-s you can use.